# Searching though XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am having issues with wrapping my head around how to search though a xml document to get certain values. It's my first time working with XML and I have tried all manner of techniques I've searched through on stackoverflow with the following two being what I think i am closest to a solution with:

'#1

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(profilePath)
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("serverconfig/collectorconfig")

For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
    MessageBox.Show(node("clientsslport").InnerText)
Next
```

'#2:

```
Dim aProfile As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim aProfileNodes As XmlNodeList
Dim aProfileNode As XmlNode

aProfile.Load(profilePath)
aProfileNodes = aProfile.SelectNodes("/clientsslport")
For Each aProfileNode In aProfileNodes
    frmDebug.lstDebug.Items.Add(aProfileNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("clientsslport").Value.ToString)
    GLOBALDTSERVERS(profileNum).serverFatClientPort = aProfileNode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("clientsslport").Value.ToString
Next
```

The goal is to point the function at a XML document, get values from the xml, and then load those values into object's i've created. Here is an example XML file that i've edited down for privacy and length:

```
<dynatrace version="6.2.4.1057">
  <serverconfig memento.version="6.2.4.1057">
    <collectorconfig usetunnel="false" useproxy="false" authstring="" serverport="6698" groupname="" communicationport="8041" proxyport="8080" embedded="true" compress="true" communicationssl="true" useproxyauthentication="false" proxyhost="" proxyusername="" usepreemtiveproxyauth="true" name="Embedded dynaTrace Collector" watchdogtimeout="10" selfmoncollector="false" serveraddress="localhost" tunnel="http://localhost:8033/tunnel">
      <agentlistenaddressconfig>
        <listenaddress agentport="9998" agentaddress="" />
      </agentlistenaddressconfig>
      <loggingconfig append="true" correlationmaxbytes="31457280" console="INFO" level="INFO" maxfiles="5" correlationmaxfiles="2" path="../log/collector/dynaTrace Collector" html="false" maxbytes="10485760" />
      <buffers agentbuffersize="32768" />
      <protocoldumps maxnumberdumps="100" />
    </collectorconfig>
    <directories>
      <storedsessions path="sessions/stored" />
      <temp path="temp" />
      <reports path="reports" />
    </directories>
    <settings>
      <collector requirecompression="false" collectoraddress="" collectorport="5001" collectorssladdress="" collectorsslport="5443" allowcollectorconnections="true" collectorauthstring="" requiressl="false" />
      <client clientssladdress="" clientport="2020" clientsslport="8443" clientaddress="" requiressl="true" />
      <frontend frontendsslport="2031" frontendaddress="localhost" frontendrequiressl="true" frontendport="2030" />
      <server tunnelenabled="true" optimizeforthroughput="true" lastvalidedition="DYNATRACE_PRODUCTION" upperdeletiontriggerlimit="153600" collectortunnelenabled="true" continuoussessionrecording="true" lowerdeletiontriggerlimit="5120" collectortunneladdress="" fqdn="<IPADDRESS>" tunneladdress="" id="-1025570809" tunnelport="8023" jmxexportmanagement="false" jmxexportmonitoring="false" autodashboardsupport="true" jmxport="1099" runtimerevision="2" name="<IPADDRESS>" watchdogtimeout="10" collectortunnelport="6608" selfmonitoringenabled="true" agentbasedselfmonitoringenabled="true" hascollector="false" />
      <purepath maxnodes="10000" />
      <buffers pathwriter="524288" pathreader="1048576" measurementwriter="32768">
        <recentlystoredpaths maxsize="250000" maxage="300000" />
      </buffers>
      <oopanalyzer port="7788" address="" logpath="../log/analysisserver" />
      <profilebackups maxbackupfiles="10" />
    </settings>
    <loggingconfig append="true" correlationmaxbytes="31457280" console="INFO" level="INFO" maxfiles="5" correlationmaxfiles="2" path="../log/server" html="false" maxbytes="10485760" />
    <http externalhttpsport="-1" httpport="8080" externalhostname="" webservicesenabled="true" httpsport="8021" webserveraddress="" externalhttpport="-1" webserverenabled="true" webserveraddressssl="" requiressl="false" />
    <webstart tunnelenabled="false" proxyauthusername="" proxyautodetectionenabled="false" proxyport="-1" tunnelssl="false" proxyenabled="false" tunneladdress="<IPADDRESS>" tunnelport="8023" anonymouswebstartenabled="true" validationtimestamp="0" webstartenabled="true" proxyaddress="" proxyauthenabled="false" />
      <loggingconfig append="true" correlationmaxbytes="31457280" console="WARNING" level="INFO" maxfiles="5" correlationmaxfiles="2" path="../log" html="false" maxbytes="10485760" />
      <plugintypeconfig loglevel="INFO" sourcebundlename="com.dynatrace.diagnostics.plugin.SnmpMonitor" bundleversion="6.2.0.1201" name="SNMP Monitor Plugin" active="true" key=
    <webui webuihttpsport="9911" webuienabled="true" />
  </serverconfig>
  <environmentdescriptor memento.version="6.2.4.1057">
    <os arch="amd64" name="Linux" version="2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64" />
    <vm vendor="Oracle Corporation" name="Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM" version="24.80-b11" />
  </environmentdescriptor>
  <repositoryconfig memento.version="6.2.4.1057" lowduration="-1" highduration="1209600000" deletefromhigh="true" midduration="5184000000" querytimeout="7200">
    <repository>
      <database name="dynatrace62" dbms="PostgreSQL" />
      <credential user="<USER>" />
      <connection port="5432" usessl="false" host="<IP>" ignorewarnnonproduction="true" useurl="false" connectonstartup="true" embededdatapath="repository" url="<IP>" autopurge_measures="true" />
    </repository>
  </repositoryconfig>
</dynatrace>
```

What i'm looking to do is get values like "8443" from "clientsslport" inside /settings/collector or "PostgreSQL" from "dbms" inside /repositoryconfig. I'm loading a lot more values from the full document but once I get an idea of how to get one, I should be able to reproduce it.

Thanks in advance for any help or insights!

Comment: If you are putting data into object in may pay to use deserialization rather than the two methods har07.  There a lots of ways to parse an xml document and the method to use will depend on the amount of data you need to extract from the xml and the size of the xml file.  Very large files you should use XMLReader which is another method similar to har07 response.

Answer (score 1):

> *"What i'm looking to do is get values like **"8443"** from **"clientsslport"** inside `/settings/collector` ..."*

As a starter, you can just provide full path from the root element all the way to target element, while using `@` + attribute name, instead of just the name, to reference XML attribute, if needed :

```
Dim xpath As String = "/dynatrace/serverconfig/settings/client/@clientsslport"
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes(xpath)
For Each node As XmlNode In nodelist
    MessageBox.Show(node.Value)
Next
```

Later, you can shorten the above XPath expression by using `descendant-or-self::node()` abbreviated syntax `//` :

```
//client/@clientsslport
```

`//` roughly means *look for the following node/attribute, anywhere within current XML document*.

---

Before going too far with `XmlDocument`, you might want to consider `.NET`'s newer XML API, the [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx) from LINQ-to-XML:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(profilePath)
Dim ports As IEnumerable(Of XAttribute) = doc.Descendants("client").Attributes("clientsslport")
For Each port As XAttribute In ports 
    MessageBox.Show(port.Value)
Next
```

Working with LINQ-to-XML, VB even provides special [XML Axis Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387033.aspx) which C# doesn't have :

```
Dim ports As IEnumerable(Of XAttribute) = doc...<client>.Attributes("clientsslport")
```

Comment: Ah- Thank you har07!!! The code works of course, but the explanation about working with xml and attributes is what i was after :) Once I can take the above and get things working to extract all the data i need and fill my data objects, i'll update!

Comment: @Phaelo Those bunch of links to the documentation should get you started to know available classes and methods in .NET XML API, I won't be able to explain better. Then the above working codes should give you idea on how to use those classes and methods for your specific XML

Comment: as for `XmlDocument`, you can read about XPath syntax independently, for example, here : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp