# VB.NET MAC OUI Lookup

Tags: regex, vb.net, extract, mac-address

Good morning,

I have created a vb.NET project that pulls the data from WireShark's HTML file found at https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf;hb=HEAD.

So far, I have been able to download the page as a string and search the string to confirm whether or not 'mac' is found in the string.

I would like to have it search for a MAC address, and output the entire line that the MAC appears on.

For example, if I search for 00-00-00-00-00-00 I would like to be able to extract the entire line, "00:00:00   Xerox   Xerox Corporation"

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub btn_search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_search.Click
    Dim mac As String = txt_MAC.Text.ToUpper
    Dim pattern As Regex = New Regex("^([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2})$")
    Dim match As Match = pattern.Match(mac)

    If match.Success Then
        mac = mac.Replace("-", ":")
        mac = mac.Substring(0, mac.Length - 9)

        Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
        Dim html As String = wc.DownloadString("https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf;hb=HEAD")
        Dim macIndex = html.IndexOf(mac) 'returns line number in string

        MsgBox("Valid MAC: " & mac)

        If html.Contains(mac) Then
            'Display MAC + Vendor. IE.... 0:00:01   Xerox   Xerox Corporation'
            ' Is there a way to read only the specified line number in the string?
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox("You must enter a valid MAC")
    End If
End Sub
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simplest idea: read the file line by line and test against the regex. If your lines can be very long using a regex with `.*`  around the pattern might slow down processing.

Comment: I used Dim macIndex = html.IndexOf(mac) to pull the index of where the searched MAC is found. I get 2472. Is there a way to read that specific line from the string?

Comment: You are doing too many redundant things. Use `Regex.Match(html, ".*" & mac & ".*").Value`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing HTML files, you can grab the [Mac address lookup list](https://devtools360.com/en/macaddress/vendorMacs.xml) as an XML file from the previous link.

Then you can use a snippet like the one in this question ["Searching through XML in VB.NET
"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376300/searching-though-xml-in-vb-net) to lookup though the XML

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit sloppy, I was able to do this with the following code:

```
        Dim wc As New Net.WebClient
        Dim html As String = wc.DownloadString("https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf;hb=HEAD")
        Dim macIndex = html.IndexOf(mac)

        If html.Contains(mac) Then
            txt_result.Text = "Searching... "
            txt_result.Text = html.Chars(macIndex) & html.Chars(macIndex + 1) & html.Chars(macIndex + 2) & html.Chars(macIndex + 3) & html.Chars(macIndex + 4) & html.Chars(macIndex + 5) & html.Chars(macIndex + 6) & html.Chars(macIndex + 7) & html.Chars(macIndex + 8) & html.Chars(macIndex + 9) & html.Chars(macIndex + 10)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of getting and concatenating every char you can just use [`String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_): `txt_result.Text = html.Substring(macIndex, 11)`